# Phaser 3 In Game Shopping Interface

Tags: ionic-framework, phaser-framework

I'm working on an Ionic project that implements Phaser 3 to include a game in it.

May i know is it possible to design a purchasing interface or a shopping menu using Phaser 3?

[image: Example of purchasing interface]

Comment: yes, phaser can render the graphics part

Comment: Yes, you can try using object oriented programming to create an Inventory, as well as a Currency system for your game.